# flutter: [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

From an IOS simulator, I am suppose to see "success" as the response after selecting avatar image, typing username, email, password, and bio description
. However I kept getting this error response, like this: " [firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."

[Update] I was able to solve this by editing Firebase Storage rules by omitting ": if false" to this :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052479/firebase-storage-an-unknown-error-occurred-please-check-the-error-payload-for)

Comment: Enable `firebase_storage` in the Firebase Console Wesbite. Your code does not mention the usage of firebase_storage, `instagram_flutter` may use it under the hood.

Comment: Thanks @MoazEl-sawaf and @Dabbel for the clues. I was able to solve this by editing the storage rules to this :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any success ???

Answer (score 6):

Just change the .putfile to .putdata this will fix this error also check the storage rules.

```
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
imgFile = File(image!.path);

UploadTask uploadTask;
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('books').child('/hogehoge.jpg');

try {
  uploadTask = ref.putData(await imgFile.readAsBytes());
  imgUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```