# Flutter Firebase Storage file upload is not working on iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I'm working on a Mobile App and want to upload images to Firebase Storage. Currently when I'm uploading an Image I get the error:
code "unknown"
message: "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."
plugin: "firebase_storage"
If I reset the iOS Simulator I can upload one picture after this I again get this error. Using Firebase Storage Emulator or a real device everything is working as expected. I tried to debug network but this tab stays empty in VSCode Flutter Devtools and in Android Studio too. I saw this question [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052479/firebase-storage-an-unknown-error-occurred-please-check-the-error-payload-for#:%7E:text=The-,console,-error%20is%20not) and tried the solution but it's not working.
My questions are now is there a way to see the server response or how can I fix this issue?

firebase_core: 2.8.0
firebase_storage: 11.2.2
firebase_auth: 4.3.0

Function for uploading:

```
 @override
  Future<Either<Failure, Unit>> uploadFile(File file, String? name) async {
    try {
      final userStorage = await firebaseStorage.userStorage();

      final fileName = _getFileName(file, name);

      final fileReference = userStorage.child(fileName);

      await fileReference.putFile(file);

      return right(unit);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.code.contains("PERMISSION_DENIED")) {
        return left(InsufficientPermissions());
      } else {
        return left(UnexpectedFailure());
      }
    }
  }
```

Firebase Rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

What have I done so far:

- Rule checked if it is working
- Used Firebase Emulator and Real Device everything was working as expected